# Android: Having Background as an Image?

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-xml

For my Android application I wish to have the `background` as an `image`, however all of the images I use are very intense and take away from the the `Textviews` etc on the app.

Is there a way to `fade` a background image so that is it provides an aesthetic background without taking away from the app's `main components`?

**Current XML code:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:background="@drawable/loginbackgroundfour">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/linearlayout_bg"
        android:padding="10dp"
        >

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:background="@drawable/button_default_bg"
            style="@style/DefaultButtonText"
           />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btnSingIn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:text="Sign In"
            style="@style/DefaultButtonText"
            android:background="@drawable/button_default_bg"
           />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btnGameRegister"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:text="Register Game"
            style="@style/DefaultButtonText"
            android:background="@drawable/button_default_bg"
           />


        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you can set alpha in layout:

```
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/main"
                android:alpha="0.5" />
```

In your case you can change your layout to be like that:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
        <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/loginbackgroundfour"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/text" 
                    android:alpha="0.5"/>
             </FrameLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
<!-- rest of your layout !-->
```

Comment: Thanks however this is setting my whole screen to be lighter, I only want the image to be lighter? Please see my edit with current xml code

Comment: This is almost perfect but the background image is not filling the full screen?

Comment: just change scaleType to fitXY and it will fill the screen. I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setAlpha()`

See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha(float))

Try this in your Java class

```
View backgroundimage = findViewById(R.id.background);
Drawable background = backgroundimage.getBackground();
background.setAlpha(80);
```

Alpha Values 0-255, 0 means fully transparent, and 255 means fully opaque

Comment: Thanks however this is setting my whole screen to be lighter, I only want the image to be lighter? Please see my edit with current xml code

Comment: my answer finds the view that uses the background image and lightens only that view..try it..